# Cabal not installing dependencies when needing profiling libraries?

Tags: haskell, profiling, cabal

I want to compile my program with profiling, so I run:

```
$ cabal configure --enable-executable-profiling
...
$ cabal build
...
    Could not find module 'Graphics.UI.GLUT':
      Perhaps you havent installed the profiling libraries for package 'GLUT-2.2.2.0'?
...
$ # indeed I have not installed the prof libs for GLUT, so..
$ cabal install -p GLUT --reinstall
...
    Could not find module 'Graphics.Rendering.OpenGL':
      Perhaps you havent installed the profiling libraries for package 'OpenGL-2.4.0.1'?
...
```

So, the problem is, that unlike cabal's usual welcome behavior, cabal doesn't resolve the dependencies and install them when needing profiling libraries.

I can work around it by resolving the dependencies manually (by following errors that appear after a while of compiling):

```
$ cabal install -p OpenGLRaw --reinstall
$ cabal install -p StateVar --reinstall
$ cabal install -p Tensor --reinstall
$ cabal install -p ObjectName --reinstall
$ cabal install -p GLURaw --reinstall
$ cabal install -p OpenGL --reinstall
$ cabal install -p GLUT --reinstall
```

And then repeat for my next dependency..

Is there a better way to do this? i.e do make cabal do the work on its own as it does for normal libraries?

Comment: I've enabled `library-profiling: True` in my `~/.cabal/config` file. From then on, any new installations will automatically enable profiling. Unfortunately that still means I had to manually reinstall for the old packages already installed. Although, after a while of doing this manually, I _now_ have most packages reinstalled with profiling enabled...

Comment: @Tom Lokhorst: Thanks. Also, this seems to be the best/only answer. So if you want, you can put it down as an answer so I can accept it

Comment: Well, it's impolite to say no to free upvotes :-) However, I do hope someone will come along with a better answer, one that would not require me to reinstall the complete Haskell Platform manually next time.

Comment: If you're on Stack and encountering this issue, [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32123475/profiling-builds-with-stack/55631220) might help you.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I've enabled `library-profiling: True` in my `~/.cabal/config` file. From then on, any new installations will automatically enable profiling.

Unfortunately that still means I had to manually reinstall for the old packages already installed. Although, after a while of doing this manually, I *now* have most packages reinstalled with profiling enabled...

Comment: I imagine this a familiar routine for many people. If only there was a command to automate this otherwise laborious task e.g. `cabal reinstall-all --with-library-profiling-enabled` .

Comment: Is it really needed recompiling of all libraries just to profile my application? Isn't there a way to switch faster between Fully optimized version (without profiling code inside) and Profiling one?

Comment: After weeks of frustrating reinstalls, I suggest that you completely uninstall everything after making the above update to your `~/.cabal/config`. There are a few ways to do this. One is `rm -rf ~/.ghc`

Answer (score 30):

From a comment by Tom Lokhorst:

> I do hope someone will come along with a better answer, one that would not require me to reinstall the complete Haskell Platform manually next time.

For future visitors:

The task of installing profiling versions of all installed libraries has become less of a chore, `cabal (cabal-install)` now keeps track of what was installed using it in the `world` file in the `.cabal` directory (on linux, that would be `$HOME/.cabal`, on Windows something like `C:\Users\%YOU%\AppData\Roaming\cabal\`, on OSX ??).

So after enabling profiling in the `config` file (in the same directory), and clearing GHC's package database (you can find the locations of the global and user db per `ghc-pkg list nonexisting`; remove the cabal-installed packages from the global database with `ghc-pkg unregister packagename` if you have any, rename or delete the entire user db - this is necessary because the `world` file only tracks explicitly installed packages, not their dependencies), installing everything with profiling support should work as follows:

```
$ cabal install --reinstall world --dry-run
```

First run with `--dry-run` to check for problems before actually reinstalling anything. If it would reinstall boot packages like `process` or `directory`, that's a bad sign, if you don't know how to handle it, ask on the `#haskell` IRC channel, one of the mailing lists, or here for guidance. If it fails to find a consistent install plan due to new versions on [hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org) of some packages which are incompatible with each other, that can usually be solved by editing the `world` file and constraining allowable versions of some packages.

Then, if you are optimistic that nothing will badly break,

```
$ cabal install --reinstall world
```

and have a nice pot of tea while GHC is busy compiling.

Comment: will this actually enable profiling if set to `True` in config? When I do a --reinstall of existing packages it seems to require the -p flag

Comment: I just tried, `cabal install --reinstall world` did reinstall with profiling enabled. Is the line `library-profiling: True` perchance commented out in the config file?

Comment: heh, thanks. I was reading the `--` as a command-line flag not comment. OOOPS!

Comment: I have removed the db in `~usr/lib/ghc/package.conf.d` and when I try to run `cabal install --reinstall world` and I get an error `can't find a package database`. Are you sure we need to delete the db?

Comment: @FordO. That looks like the global package database, the user db is typically under `~/.ghc/$GHC_Version`. Only the user db can be deleted, removing the entire global package database breaks your GHC. If you have a backup of the package db, reinstate that, otherwise I'm afraid you'll need to reinstall GHC. From the global db, only packages installed with cabal should be unregistered.

Answer (score 16):

Daniel Fischer's answer looks good, but for some reason my ~/.cabal/world library only contained entries for libraries directly installed, and not their dependencies.

Instead, I dumped out a list of all installed libraries using

```
$ ghc-pkg list > list
```

This lists the libraries installed system-wide and locally. Therefore, I edited the `list` file to remove the first portion (containing libraries installed system-wide) leaving only the lines after `/home/<user>/.ghc/...`. Finally, I ran

```
$ cabal install --reinstall $(cat list)
```

This worked for me. You should maybe do `--dry-run` first. Then go make a pot of tea. Or bake a cake.

Comment: According to Daniel's answer above, the world file is only supposed to contain directly installed packages.  I think the idea is that cabal will resolve the dependencies for you, and they may change over time.

Comment: There are some additional helpful comments here:

https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/275

Answer (score 4):

it appears there is no way right now: [Ticket #282 - profiling versions of libraries not managed well](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/hackage/ticket/282) ["As usual the problem is lack of devevloper time to implement all these
nice features we all want."](http://www.mail-archive.com/haskell-cafe@haskell.org/msg80376.html)

Answer (score 0):

For visitors 2016+: Just install `ghc-prof`

> Debian Linux Systems:
>
> `sudo apt-get install ghc-prof`
>
> Arch Linux Systems:
>
> `sudo pacman -S ghc-prof`

Comment: There's currently no package `ghc-prof` in the pacman repositories.