# Reinstall all depending packages with cabal manually

Tags: haskell, cabal, cabal-install

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cabal not installing dependencies when needing profiling libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704421/cabal-not-installing-dependencies-when-needing-profiling-libraries)

Here is the situation. I want to install\reinstall package **A** with some new options or flags (for example I've add `library-profiling: True` in `~/.cabal/config`).

```
cabal install --reinstall A
```

Package **A** depends on package **B**, which installed without support that options. That why (if I'm understanding that correctly) tells me that:

```
Could not find module `B':
  Perhaps you haven't installed the profiling libraries for package `B'?
  Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

So I need to reinstall package **B** and then try to install package **A**:

```
cabal install --reinstall B
cabal install --reinstall A
```

All I want is to tell cabal that I need to reinstall all packages that depends on **A** automatically. How can I do that?

Comment: Check http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2010-August/082396.html and http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/hackage/ticket/282

Comment: I suggest we reopen this question.  The cited dup is over a year old and since then we, as a community, have developed the cab and cabal-dev tools which offer better solutions.