# Profile Haskell without installing profiling libraries for all dependencies

Tags: haskell, profiling

I wish to profile my program written in Haskell.

On compilation, I am told that I do not have profiling libraries for certain dependencies (e.g., `criterion`) installed and `cabal` aborts.

I have no interest in profiling parts of those dependencies; code called from `main` doesn't even use them.

How can I profile my application without installing profiling libraries I don't need and without removing all those dependencies?

Comment: You can't. Just install them, what's the problem?

Comment: 1) I don't need them, 2) Installing them is incredibly tedious: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704421/cabal-not-installing-dependencies-when-needing-profiling-libraries

Comment: While I agree that it's tedious, your claim that you don't need them is clearly false.

Comment: I will accept this as an answer if you post it. It doesn't solve my problem, but the anwswer seems to be "not yet possible".

Comment: Why not use use -prof rather than criterion?  [Chapter 5](http://lambda.haskell.org/platform/doc/current/ghc-doc/users_guide/index.html) of the Platform docs. Wait, what Haskell compiler are you using? Haskell Platform?  What version?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A good way to circumvent having to compile *everything* with profiling is to use cabal sandbox. It allows you to set up a sandbox for one application only, and thereby you won't have to re-install your entire `~/.cabal` prefix. You'll need a recent version of Cabal, so run `cabal update && cabal install cabal-install` first.

Once you initialise a sandbox, create a file `cabal.config` to include the necessary directives (in your case `library-profiling: True`; `executable-profiling: True` may also be handy.)

A side-effect of this is that you can test your code with dependencies that need not be installed globally, for example, experimental versions, or outdated versions.

EDIT: btw, I don't think you need to have profiling enabled for `criterion` to work. In any case, it works for me *without* profiling being enabled. Just write a `Main` module that contains `main = defaultMain benchmarks` where `benchmarks` has type `[Benchmark]`, i.e. a list of benchmarks that you've written.

You then compile that file (say, we call it `benchmarks.hs` with `ghc --make -o bench benchmarks.hs`, and run the program, `./bench` with the appropriate arguments (consult the criterion documentation for details. A good default argument is, say `./bench -o benchmarks.html` which will generate a nifty report similar to [this one](http://bos.github.com/criterion/))

Comment: I guess naming `criterion` was implying the wrong thing: it was just an example of a dependency I have which I don't want to profile. I should rather have said something like *"My application uses `hunit` for testing, but I do not wish to profile the testing code itself and there fore would like to avoid installing that with profiling enabled"*.

Comment: Criterion is only good if you want to compare two functions *time-wise*. It doesn't tell you much about *why* your code is slow/fast. In order to find memory leaks or lazy thunks, you will still need heap profiling, which needs the `-prof` switch.

Comment: For anybody who reads this now: `cabal-dev` has largely been superseeded by *sandboxes* in Cabal itself.

Comment: Good call! [Here's the documentation](http://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/installing-packages.html#developing-with-sandboxes) on sandboxes within the new Cabal. Make sure you're using at least version 1.18

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem this week, and although I had recompiled everything by hand, I was instructed in the IRC channel to do the following:

1. Go to your cabal config file [(in case you don't know where)](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Cabal-Install)
2. Edit the line for enable library profiling (and while you are at it, enable documentation)
3. Run Cabal Install World

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned in the question you refer to in your comment, a good way to solve this problem in the future is to enable profiling in the cabal configuration. This way all libraries are installed with profiling support. This might not be a satisfying solution but I guess many are opting for it.

If you are only interested in getting an impression of the memory usage of your program you can generate a heap profile of your program using `-hT`. More precisely, you have to compile the program with `-rtsopts` to enable RTS options then execute it using `+RTS -hT`. The compiler generates a file with the extension `hp`. You can convert the `hp` file into a postscript file with a heap profile using `hp2ps`. This should work without any profiling support, but note that I am too lazy to verify it as I have installed all libraries with profiling support ; )

Comment: Wow, you are right! Heap profiles don't need `-prof`, so my above problem does not arise if I only need space profiling. Nice.

Comment: Please note that this is only the case for `-hT`, that is type-based heap profiling. There are other profiling types like retainer profiling that still need `-prof`.