# How do I enable profiling in a cabal-dev installation?

Tags: haskell, profiling, cabal

I'm trying to profile a program windingnumber which has some few dependencies. Per Aleksander Dmitrov's answer in [Profile Haskell without installing installing profiling libraries for all dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12207698/profile-haskell-without-installing-installing-profiling-libraries-for-all-depend), I'm using cabal-dev to (attempt to) build all of the dependencies with profiling enabled. I have tried

- `cabal-dev install --config=./cabal-dev.config`, where cabal-dev.config is

  ```
  library-profiling: True
  executable-profiling: True
  package-db: /home/christopher/school/senior/senior_thesis/windingnumber_integration/cabal-dev/packages-7.6.1.conf
  local-repo: /home/christopher/school/senior/senior_thesis/windingnumber_integration/cabal-dev/packages
  user-install: False
  remote-repo: hackage.haskell.org:http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive
  remote-repo-cache: /home/christopher/.cabal/packages
  optimization: True
  build-summary: /home/christopher/school/senior/senior_thesis/windingnumber_integration/cabal-dev/logs/build.log
  remote-build-reporting: anonymous
  optimization: True

  install-dirs user
    prefix: /home/christopher/school/senior/senior_thesis/windingnumber_integration/cabal-dev/
  install-dirs global
  ```
- `cabal-dev install --cabal-install-arg='--enable-library-profiling' --cabal-install-arg='--enable-executable-profiling'`

(with `rm -rf cabal-dev` in between, of course, to start from a pristine environment.) In each case, I get:

```
arch% cabal-dev/bin/windingnumber +RTS -p
cabal-dev/bin/windingnumber +RTS -p
windingnumber: the flag -p requires the program to be built with -prof
windingnumber: 
windingnumber: Usage: <prog> <args> [+RTS <rtsopts> | -RTS <args>] ... --RTS <args>
<snip>
```

---i.e., profiling is not enabled. How can I enable it?

**ETA Solution:** add `-prof` to ghc-options in the .cabal file for the project did it. Apparently setting `executable-profiling: True" in the cabal-dev config didn't do it. Thanks to Daniel Fischer.

Comment: Looks like you didn't build the executable with the `-prof` flag. How did you build `windingnumber`?

Comment: Aha. adding -prof to ghc-options in my .cabal file fixed things. Thanks!

Comment: You may want a finer-grained profiling than the default, so `-fprof-auto` may be a good addition.

Comment: Yep. That was indeed much more useful.

Comment: Wouldn't calling cabal-dev this way: `cabal-dev install --enable-library-profiling --enable-executable-profiling` also work? In case you want to get rid of the config file.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like `cabal-dev` rewrites `./cabal-dev/cabal.config` every time it runs. However, you can edit `~/.cabal/share/cabal-dev-$VERSION/admin/cabal-config.in` to set the default values:

```sh
$  vim ~/.cabal/share/cabal-dev-0.9.1/admin/cabal-config.in
# Set executable-profiling and library-profiling to True
$ cabal unpack ghc-core
$ cd ghc-core-0.5.6
$ cabal-dev install --dependencies-only
$ cabal-dev configure -p
$ cabal-dev build
$ ./dist/build/ghc-core/ghc-core +RTS -p
# much success
```

If you don't want to enable profiling for all projects managed with `cabal-dev`, use the `--extra-config-file` option (`--config` just sets the location of the auto-generated config file):

```sh
$ cat cabal-dev.config 
executable-profiling: True
library-profiling: True
$ cabal-dev --extra-config-file='./cabal-dev.config' install
$ ./cabal-dev/bin/ghc-core +RTS -p
# success
```

Using the `ghc-options` field in the .cabal file for enabling profiling is not recommended - you don't want everyone who installs your package from Hackage to build with profiling. Use `cabal-dev configure -p --ghc-options="-fprof-auto"` to enable profiling for the current build only.

Comment: Ah. That's good to know, though it doesn't solve my problem (I'm specifying an alternate config file with --config.)

Comment: @ChristopherWhite Apparently `--config` just sets the location of the cabal-dev's config file, which is auto-generated on each startup. You need to use `--extra-config-file` instead. I've updated my answer.

Comment: That explains things; I should have read the documentation more carefully. Sorry about that, and thank you.