# Why does this Haskell program perform so poorly?

Tags: performance, haskell

I'm a Haskell newbie and I'm lost as to how this program performs so poorly. I tried forcing strict variables in various places but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Here is my code (the purpose of this program is produce the frequencies of the input bytes found from standard input):

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}

import Control.Concurrent (forkIO, killThread)
import Control.Concurrent.MVar
import qualified Data.IntMap as IntMap
import Data.IntMap.Strict (IntMap)
import Control.Monad.Fix
import Control.Monad (when)
import qualified Data.Char as Char
import qualified System.IO as IO
import System.IO (hSetBinaryMode, hFlush)
import Data.List as List
import Text.PrettyPrint.Boxes as Boxes
import Text.Printf (printf)
import Data.Function

data BFreq = BFreq Integer (IntMap Integer)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn "analyze data from stdin"
  hSetBinaryMode IO.stdin True
  mv <- newEmptyMVar
  tid <- forkIO $ statusUpdater mv
  bf <- run mv
  killThread tid
  displayResults bf

resultTable :: [[String]] -> Box
resultTable rows =
  Boxes.hsep 4 Boxes.left boxed_cols
  where
    cols       = transpose rows
    boxed_cols = map (Boxes.vcat Boxes.left . map text) cols

displayResults :: BFreq -> IO ()
displayResults (BFreq n counts) = do
  putStrLn $ "read " ++ (show n) ++ " bytes"
  when (n > 0) (displayFreqs n counts)

displayFreqs :: Integer -> IntMap Integer -> IO ()
displayFreqs n counts =
  do
    putStrLn "frequencies:"
    Boxes.printBox $ resultTable rows
  where
    cmp x y       = compare (snd y) (snd x)
    sorted_counts = List.sortBy cmp $ IntMap.assocs counts

    intdiv :: Integer -> Integer -> Float
    intdiv a b = (fromIntegral a) / (fromIntegral b)

    percent y    = printf "%.2f" (100*intdiv y n)
    show_byte x  = (show $ Char.chr x) ++ " (" ++ (show x) ++ "):"
    show_count y = (percent y) ++ "% (" ++ (show y) ++ ")"

    rows = map (\(x,y) -> [show_byte x, show_count y]) sorted_counts


run :: MVar Integer -> IO BFreq
run mv = 
  fn mv 0 IntMap.empty 
  where
    fn mv !n !mp =
      do
        tryPutMVar mv n
        eof <- IO.isEOF
        if eof
          then return $ BFreq n mp
          else do
            b <- getChar
            fn mv (1+n) (new_map b)
      where
        k x       = Char.ord x
        old_val x = IntMap.findWithDefault 0 (k x) mp
        new_map x = IntMap.insert (k x) ((old_val x)+1) mp

statusUpdater :: MVar Integer -> IO ()
statusUpdater mv = 
  do
    takeMVar mv >>= print_progress
    statusUpdater mv
  where
    print_progress n = 
      do
        putStr $ "\rbytes: "
        when (gbs > 0) $ putStr $ (show gbs) ++ " GBs "
        when (mbs > 0) $ putStr $ (show mbs) ++ " MBs "
        when (kbs > 0) $ putStr $ (show kbs) ++ " KBs "
        when (gbs < 1 && mbs < 1 && kbs < 1) $ putStr $ (show bs) ++ " Bs "
        hFlush IO.stdout
      where
        (gbs, gbr)   = quotRem n 0x40000000
        (mbs, mbr)   = quotRem gbr 0x100000
        (kbs, bs)    = quotRem mbr 0x400
```

here is what happens when I run it (note: I am compiling with -O2):

```
$> cabal build -v                                                                                             
creating dist/build                                                                                                                       
creating dist/build/autogen                                                                                                                 
Building bfreq-0.1.0.0...                                                                                                                   
Preprocessing executable 'bfreq' for bfreq-0.1.0.0...                                                                                       
Building executable bfreq...                                                                                                                  
creating dist/build/bfreq                                                                                                                     
creating dist/build/bfreq/bfreq-tmp                                                                                                           
/usr/bin/ghc --make -o dist/build/bfreq/bfreq -hide-all-packages -fbuilding-cabal-package -package-conf dist/package.conf.inplace -i -idist/build/bfreq/bfreq-tmp -i. -idist/build/autogen -Idist/build/autogen -Idist/build/bfreq/bfreq-tmp -optP-include -optPdist/build/autogen/cabal_macros.h -odir dist/build/bfreq/bfreq-tmp -hidir dist/build/bfreq/bfreq-tmp -stubdir dist/build/bfreq/bfreq-tmp -package-id base-4.5.0.0-40b99d05fae6a4eea95ea69e6e0c9702 -package-id boxes-0.1.3-e03668bca38fe3e879f9d695618ddef3 -package-id containers-0.5.3.1-80819105034e34d03d22b1c20d6fd868 -O -O2 -rtsopts -XHaskell98 ./bfreq.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( bfreq.hs, dist/build/bfreq/bfreq-tmp/Main.o )
Linking dist/build/bfreq/bfreq ...
$> cat /dev/urandom | head -c 9999999 > test_data
$> cat ./test_data | ./dist/build/bfreq/bfreq +RTS -sstderr
analyze data from stdin
bytes: 9 MBs 521 KBs read 9999999 bytes
frequencies:
'\137' (137):    0.40% (39642)
'H' (72):        0.40% (39608)
<...>
'L' (76):        0.39% (38617)
'\246' (246):    0.39% (38609)
'I' (73):        0.38% (38462)
'q' (113):       0.38% (38437)
   9,857,106,520 bytes allocated in the heap
  14,492,245,840 bytes copied during GC
   3,406,696,360 bytes maximum residency (13 sample(s))
      14,691,672 bytes maximum slop
            6629 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                    Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0     18348 colls,     0 par   10.90s   10.90s     0.0006s    0.0180s
  Gen  1        13 colls,     0 par   15.20s   19.65s     1.5119s    12.6403s

  INIT    time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
  MUT     time   14.45s  ( 14.79s elapsed)
  GC      time   26.10s  ( 30.56s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
  Total   time   40.55s  ( 45.35s elapsed)

  %GC     time      64.4%  (67.4% elapsed)

  Alloc rate    682,148,818 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity  35.6% of total user, 31.9% of total elapsed
```

So unless I'm misinterpreting the above debug output, my program is using 6 GB?
The test data is less than 10 MB, so what's going on?

Any general advice on how to approach a problem like this in Haskell would be nice too. In otherwords, should I avoid Haskell for this kind of I/O-centric stuff? Should I be using the pipes library for this kind of thing?

EDIT:
Thanks for the help, correctly importing the strict version of IntMap fixes the memory issues.

I haven't been able to get the profiling (-fprof-auto) to work because it seems none of my packages are compiled for profiling. I solved the lack of profiling base libraries by installing the ghc profiling package for my OS (ubuntu: ghc-prof), but according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704421/cabal-not-installing-dependencies-when-needing-profiling-libraries) I'll need to manually re-install all my haskell libraries for profiling. I don't have the time to do this at the moment, so I'm just putting this link here for the benefit of anyone who has a similar problem.

Comment: Have you tried profiling it to find what functions are eating up so much memory?  It's likely that there's only a single function that is eating up the memory, so once you know which one it'll make it easier to find the memory leak.

Comment: A general guideline: If a standard library function does what you want, then use it - it's probably implemented better. In your `statusUpdater`, you have an infinite loop that could have been implemented with `Control.Monad.forever`.

Comment: Also: in your `run` function, you work on the `IntMap` by first looking up the value (`findWithDefault`), and then modifying it (`insert`). `IntMap` provides an `alter` function which can do what you want in one go.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you compile with `-fprof-auto` as per [the GHC guide chapter on profiling](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/profiling.html), you'll see large allocation happening in `run.fn.new_map` and `run.fn`.

The code in question:

```
new_map x = IntMap.insert (k x) ((old_val x)+1) mp
```

Suspicion: `((old_val x)+1)` is creating a chain of unevaluated thunks.  Proposed change:

```
new_map x = let ov  = old_val x + 1 in
            ov `seq` IntMap.insert (k x) ov mp
```

Voila! Allocations, GC, and memory use are all way down.

EDIT: You probably intended to `import qualified Data.IntMap.Strict as IntMap`, making this change unnecessary.

Comment: Damn, you beat me ;). Turns out that changing the import to the `Strict` version is actually all that's needed. Memory usage goes down to 2mb.