# Haskell remove reference to List in do(IO)

Tags: haskell, garbage-collection, lazy-evaluation

I'm new to Haskell(also to FP and lazy-evaluation). I'm trying to write a log analyzer, but currently it allocates 4G of memory and therefore crashes even for logs as small as 90M.

I stripped the program to just the part that collects frequent referer pages. Also, I store them inside a ternary trie(since most URL's share common prefix), so they shouldn't take that much memory.

So, I'm expecting the program to just take a few MB's of memory by just storing those referers, not that many.

I think the main culprit is the `readStats` function in main file below:

```hs
-- main.hs
import Record
import Output
import Stats

import System.Environment    
import Data.List
import qualified Data.ByteString as B
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as C8

readStats :: String -> IO Stats
readStats p = do
    f <- B.readFile p
    return $ foldl' 
               (\t l -> applyEither t (parseLogLine l)) 
               emptyStats
               (C8.lines f)
    where applyEither t (Right rec) = applyRecord t rec 
          applyEither t (Left err)  = applyError t err 

main :: IO ()
main = do
    args <- getArgs
    stats <- readStats $ head args 
    putStrLn $ page stats
```

I'm thinking that since I'm assigning the result from `B.readFile` to `f`, the whole file is stored in memory as `[Char]` which I imagine takes a lot more memory because of pointers.

How can I make the GC to collect from `f` as soon as I parsed the required line in `parseLogLine`?

Also, all suggestions about structure/coding style are greatly appreciated, since I'm new to Haskell.

Thank you.

Edit: Here are the other functions/structures:

Trie:

```hs
data Trie a = Node Char (Trie a) (Trie a) (Trie a) (Maybe a)
              | Empty deriving (Show, Eq) 

sanify :: Trie a -> Trie a
sanify (Node _ Empty Empty Empty Nothing) = Empty
sanify (Node _ Empty lo    Empty Nothing) = lo
sanify (Node _ Empty Empty hi    Nothing) = hi
sanify t = t 

update :: Trie a -> String -> (Maybe a -> Maybe a) -> Trie a
update _ [] _ = error "Can not insert an empty string to a Trie"
update Empty (x:[]) f = sanify $ Node x Empty Empty Empty (f Nothing) 
update Empty (x:xs) f = sanify $ Node x (update Empty xs f) Empty Empty Nothing
update (Node c eq lo hi val) xss@(x:xs) f = 
    case x `compare` c of
        LT -> sanify $ Node c eq (update lo xss f) hi val 
        GT -> sanify $ Node c eq lo (update hi xss f) val 
        EQ -> case xs of
                [] -> sanify $ Node c eq lo hi (f val)
                _  -> sanify $ Node c (update eq xs f) lo hi val
```

Record:

```hs
import Network.URL

data Record = Record {
    ip :: IP, 
    date :: UTCTime,
    method :: Method,
    path :: URL,
    referer :: Maybe URL,
    status :: Integer,
    userAgent :: String
} deriving (Show, Eq) 

parseRecord :: Parser Record
parseRecord = do
    ip <- parseIP
    P8.skipWhile (/= '[')
    date <- parseDate
    P.string (B8.pack " \"")
    method <- P8.takeWhile (/= ' ')
    .....


data LogError = LogError {msg :: String, line :: B8.ByteString}
parseLogLine :: B8.ByteString -> Either LogError Record
parseLogLine line = case parseOnly parseRecord line of
                        Right a -> Right a
                        Left msg -> Left $ LogError msg line
```

Stats:

```hs
type StringCounter = T.Trie Int 
increment :: StringCounter -> String -> StringCounter
increment t s = T.update t s incNode
                where incNode n = case n of  
                                    Nothing -> Just 1
                                    Just i -> Just (i+1)

sortCounter :: StringCounter -> [(String, Int)]
sortCounter = sortWith (negate.snd) . T.toList

data Stats = Stats {
    paths :: StringCounter,
    referers :: StringCounter,
    errors :: [LogError]
}

emptyStats :: Stats
emptyStats = Stats T.Empty T.Empty []

buildStats :: [Record] -> Stats
buildStats = foldl' applyRecord emptyStats 

applyRecord :: Stats -> Record -> Stats
applyRecord env rec = env {
    paths = increment (paths env) (exportURL $ path rec),
    referers = case referer rec of
                 Nothing -> referers env 
                 Just ref -> increment (referers env) (exportURL $ stripParams ref)
    }   

applyError :: Stats -> LogError -> Stats
applyError env err = env { errors = err : errors env }
```

Comment: The code you pasted looks pretty fine, I think the problem probably lies in `parseLogLine` or `applyRecord`. `f` is a tight bytestring, that doesn't consume any more memory than necessary. — As for recommendations, looks quite nice too but you could shorten that lambda to `\t -> applyEither t . parseLogLine`.

Comment: Thanks, posted some more code. Edit: Thank you for your suggestions. Where do you think I'm consuming that much (Gigs of memory)? Small logs completes nicely, so there aren't any infinite loops etc.

Comment: It looks like your `applyRecord` probably builds up thunks (remember that `seq` in `foldl'` only evaluates the accumulating value to weak head normal form, i.e. you only get strictness in the outer constructor); try using some strict fields in your datatypes. You can also use `Data.ByteString.Lazy.readFile` to read your input lazily, as required by your computation (like prelude `readFile`)

Comment: Have you tried profiling (see, e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20850260/why-does-this-haskell-program-perform-so-poorly/20850753)?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't really look at your code, but there is a general advice: use conduits, Luke. For handling streams of data — like logs — they are really excellent. Most importantly, they give you the ability to run in O(1) space. Don't mess with lazy IO, like readFile; it's for throwaway code.