# How to install ghc and base with profiling support, in Haskell Platform

Tags: haskell, profiling, haskell-platform

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31727944/1350864) to the problem I'm having suggests running e.g. `sudo apt-get install ghc-prof` on Debian systems to install base libraries with profiling support. However I've installed Haskell Platform (through the 'Generic' option). How do I (re)install ghc/base with profiling support?

Comment: I would recommend you to use stack: https://haskell-lang.org/get-started

Comment: But I am using Haskell Platform, as suggested here: https://www.haskell.org/downloads

Comment: The download page also mentions Stack. IMO, it's much easier and better to just rely on Stack for managing your GHCs.

Comment: Okay, but the Haskell Platform feature specifically list mentions "Support for profiling and code coverage analysis". I don't see how to enable this, though.

Comment: @Sibi you really need to stop commenting on every question by telling people to use a different tool. It is not appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

The Haskell Platform comes with profiling libraries for base. If you've installed the platform, and are using the platform-installed libraries, then you should "just" have it already. The only possibility is if you've still got your distro-installed GHC in your path, and are using that instead...