# How to compile dependencies for profiling in a cabal sandbox

Tags: haskell, cabal-install

I'm trying to compile one of my executables with profiling options. I added the `-prof` options in my cabal file. When I do that, I get a message saying

```
Could not find module ‘Package-X’
Perhaps you haven't installed the profiling libraries for package ‘package-x’?
Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

How do I do that? I tried `cabal install --only-dependency --reinstall` and I get the following response :

```
All the requested packages are already installed:
Use --reinstall if you want to reinstall anyway.
```

I already used  `--reinstall` what should I do ? I also tried `cabal configure --enable-profiling-libraries` etc ...

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704421/cabal-not-installing-dependencies-when-needing-profiling-libraries) question solve your problem?

Comment: It kind of solve it. `cabal install --reinstall world` did something. But I still can't get the profiling to be on for my executable. If I add `-prof` in the cabal file, it complains it's not needed. If I remove it `+RTS -p` complaining the binary hasn't been compiled with profiling support ...

Comment: Did you add `library-profiling: True` to your `.cabal/config` file?  That seemed to be the real trick for getting libraries with profiling to be installed.

Comment: No I didn't. I thought `cabal configure --enable-library-profiling` would do the trick. However, my problem might be that I'm using different sandbox sources ... I'm trying to recompile them

Comment: Setting `library-profiling` to `True` in the `.cabal/config` file did the trick. But I had to delete the sandbox (`cabal sandbox delete; cabal sandbox init; cabal sandbox install`). Which reinstalled everything (normal+profiled libraries). I would have prefered to avoid reinstalling the normal one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704421/cabal-not-installing-dependencies-when-needing-profiling-libraries) suggested by bheklilr helped but didn't straight away.

I ended up adding `library-profiling: True` in my `.cabal/config` file and reinstall everything.
`cabal install --reinstall wolrd` didn't work, maybe because I'm inside a sandbox. However, the good
things about sandboxes is that you can ditch them away so I reinstalled everything using

```
cabal sandbox delete
cabal sandbox init
cabal install
```

Even though this solution worked, it's not satisfactory for the following reasons :

- I had to modify `.cabal/config` which is a global file, whereas in a ideal wolrd
  I should have had to only modify my sandbox. However, I didn't try to create a local cabal config file
- I had to reinstall EVERYTHING, ie the profiling version of each library as well as the plain version, which was already installed.

Comment: According to the documentation (https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/installing-packages.html#developing-with-sandboxes), you can set up project-local config files by creating a file called `cabal.config` in the same directory as your `cabal.sandbox.config`. This should allow you to set the `library-profiling: True` option for your sandbox.