# How to prevent profiling dependency issue before Genesis

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal

It is well know that [profiling large packages almost always require destroying and rebuilding the world](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704421/cabal-not-installing-dependencies-when-needing-profiling-libraries). However, is there anyway to avoid this when starting fresh? How can I enable benchmark and profiling the first time I install GHC platform on a new machine?

Comment: Isn't the answer in the other question sufficient enough, e.g. configure your `~/.cabal/config`?

Comment: That still requires reinstalling the platform if you encounter a package that depends on some infrastructures, e.g. haddock uses cabal.