# Profiling builds with Stack

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack

How do I tell `stack` to build my executable and all its dependencies with `-prof`?

Simply adding it to `ghc-options` in the `.cabal` file is not enough, because it only tries to build the executable with profiling enabled, which fails.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

## Profiling builds with Stack 1.0.0 and newer

To build with profiling enabled:

```
stack build --profile
```

**You may need to run `stack clean` first**, but [this should be fixed in Stack 1.5.0](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/2984).

To profile:

```
stack exec --profile -- <your program> +RTS <profiling options>
```

where for `<profiling options>` you might want `-p` for time profiling or `-h` for memory profiling. For time profiling, the profile appears in `./<your program>.prof`, and for memory profiling, the profile appears in `./<your program>.hp`.

See [GHC profiling documentation](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/profiling.html) for more profiling options.

## Avoiding unnecessary rebuilding of local packages (fixed in Stack 2.X?)

Due to a [long standing Stack
issue](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/1132),
switching between profiling and non-profiling builds can cause a lot
of unnecessary rebuilding of local packages and `extra-deps`. To work
around this, you can use separate build caches for your profiling and
non-profiling builds. For example, where you use `stack <cmd>` for
non profiling you can use

```
stack --work-dir .stack-work-profile --profile <cmd>
```

for a profiling version of `<cmd>`. This uses a separate 
cache in `.stack-work-profile` for profiling artifacts,
whereas non profiling artifacts will be preserved in the default
`.stack-work` cache.

## Profiling builds with Stack versions before 1.0.0 (i.e. from 2015)

To build with profiling enabled:

```
stack build --executable-profiling --library-profiling --ghc-options="-fprof-auto -rtsopts"
```

To profile:

```
stack exec -- <your program> +RTS <profiling options>
```

## Example for Stack 1.0.0 and newer

Suppose you have a package called `test` with a single executable `test` defined by `main` here:

```
module Main where

main :: IO ()
main = do
  print $ foo 0

foo :: Int -> Int
foo x = fooSub (x+1)
  where
    fooSub x = bar (x+1)

bar :: Int -> Int
bar x = barSub (x+1)
  where
    barSub x = barSubSub (x+1)
      where
        barSubSub x = x+1
```

then doing `stack build --profile && stack exec -- test +RTS -p` will produce a file `./test.prof` which includes

```
                                                                                                individual      inherited
COST CENTRE                 MODULE                SRC                        no.     entries  %time %alloc   %time %alloc

  [... many lines omitted ...]
  main                      Main                  src/Main.hs:(4,1)-(5,15)    97          0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
   foo                      Main                  src/Main.hs:(8,1)-(10,24)   98          1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
    foo.fooSub              Main                  src/Main.hs:10:5-24         99          1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
     bar                    Main                  src/Main.hs:(13,1)-(17,46) 100          1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
      bar.barSub            Main                  src/Main.hs:(15,5)-(17,46) 101          1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
       bar.barSub.barSubSub Main                  src/Main.hs:17:9-46        102          1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 main                       Main                  src/Main.hs:(4,1)-(5,15)    95          0    0.0   20.5     0.0   20.5
```

I.e., there is profiling information for all definitions, including
local definitions in `where` clauses.

If you only want to profile top-level definitions, you can build with
the GHC option `-fprof-auto-top` instead: doing `stack build --profile --ghc-options=-fprof-auto-top && stack exec -- test +RTS -p` produces a `./test.prof` which includes

```
                                                                                individual      inherited
COST CENTRE MODULE                SRC                        no.     entries  %time %alloc   %time %alloc

 [... many lines omitted ...]
  main      Main                  src/Main.hs:(4,1)-(5,15)    97          0    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
   foo      Main                  src/Main.hs:(8,1)-(10,24)   98          1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
    bar     Main                  src/Main.hs:(13,1)-(17,46)  99          1    0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0
 main       Main                  src/Main.hs:(4,1)-(5,15)    95          0    0.0   20.5     0.0   20.5
```

instead.

Finally, note that `stack build --profile` also turns on stack
traces. If you change the program so that `barSubSub x = error $ show x`, then running `stack build --profile && stack exec test` produces

```
test: 4
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at src/Main.hs:17:23 in main:Main
CallStack (from -prof):
  Main.bar.barSub.barSubSub (src/Main.hs:17:9-36)
  Main.bar.barSub (src/Main.hs:(15,5)-(17,36))
  Main.bar (src/Main.hs:(13,1)-(17,36))
  Main.foo.fooSub (src/Main.hs:10:5-24)
  Main.foo (src/Main.hs:(8,1)-(10,24))
  Main.main (src/Main.hs:(4,1)-(5,15))
  Main.CAF:lvl8_r4Fc (<no location info>)
```

Pretty cool!

Comment: This doesn't work. Using stack exec my-exe +RTS -p shows executables haven't been compiled with -prof, and trying to do so shows that ld cannot find the profiled versions of the libraries.

Comment: This worked for me: `stack install --enable-executable-profiling --enable-library-profiling --ghc-options="-fprof-auto -rtsopts"`

Comment: How do you execute it / profile it after the build has finished?

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski: I just edited my answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: Could you put the part about `.stack-work-profile` first? The first time I read this answer, I saw the first line and did it, and regretted it once I read on.

Comment: Hi from 2019! Today with Stack 2.1.3, these instructions did not work for me. I needed to add `--profile` to the `stack exec` call as well. This worked: `stack build --profile && stack exec --profile -- my-exe +RTS ...`

Comment: @Calvin: thanks for the heads up! Ijust  updated my answer to include `--profile` in the `stack exec` command. My brief testing indicates that Stack 2.x versions are smarter than before about profiling, automatically keeping the regular and `--profile` versions separate, but I can't find the documentation for this. I believe this is the relevant Stack issue, but it's still open: https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/4032

Comment: What do the numbers mean in `src/Main.hs:(4,1)-(5,15)`? I initially thought they're range of line numbers but they dont make sense; also they dont seem to match in my case.. The first of each pair may define a range of lines?

Comment: Ok. It seems they indicate the pair of the cursor locations.. as in the code-snippet _from_ and _to_ ..

Answer (score 14):

I had this problem as well and found that the problem was in the invocation:

`stack exec my-exe +RTS -p` passes `-p` to stack instead of my-exe. This works:

```
stack exec -- my-exe +RTS -p
```

Answer (score 6):

For `stack build`, `stack bench` and `stack test` you can just use `stack build/bench/test --profile`. You may have to `stack clean` first to get it to recompile with profiling.

For `stack build` you will still have to pass `+RTS -p` or whatever option you need (see [GHC User Guide](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/profiling.html#time-and-allocation-profiling)) when running the executable as in [@Tomáš Janoušek answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34678897/2246434).

You can also find more information in the [debugging section of the stack user guide](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/blob/master/doc/GUIDE.md#debugging).

Comment: You can also add "--force-dirty" to the end of your stack build command to force it to recompile.

Comment: did you mean to say `stack exec`?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming a project called `project-name`, this is how I get a time and heap profile (with colors):

1. Add dependencies to the `build-depends` section of `project-name.cabal`
2. Get dependent packages: `stack build`
3. From inside `project-name/app` compile the program with [profiling enabled](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/profiling.html#ghc-flag--prof): `stack ghc -- -prof -fprof-auto -rtsopts -O2 Main.hs`
4. Then create the [heap](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/profiling.html#rts-options-for-heap-profiling) and [time](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/profiling.html#rts-flag--p) profile `./Main +RTS -hc -p`. This will produce `Main.hp` and `Main.prof`
5. Turn the heap profile into a [PostScript file](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/profiling.html#hp2ps-rendering-heap-profiles-to-postscript) and then into a PDF chart with colors: `stack exec -- hp2ps -c Main.hp && ps2pdf Main.ps`

That's the heap profile from the PDF:

[image: heap_profile_with_colors]

Comment: @LupusOssorum: I don't know if there's a way to turn a `.prof` file into PDF. But there are visualization tools for `.prof` files such as [profiteur](https://jaspervdj.be/posts/2014-02-25-profiteur-ghc-prof-visualiser.html), [professor](https://github.com/vincenthz/professor), and [viewprof](https://github.com/maoe/viewprof).

Answer (score 1):

The concise way to run Stack project with profiling is to use [stack run](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/run_command/) command, e.g.:

```
stack run --profile -- +RTS -p
```

This command will first build your project with profiling enabled and then execute it with `+RTS -p` flag.

Note that if you use `stack exec` command instead you need to first invoke `stack build` and re-invoke it every time your source changes since `stack exec` does not rebuild project even if it is stale.
On the other hand `stack run` will automatically rebuild your project before executing it if there is a pending change.